# how did my Html.Editor get its value which is not provided inside my Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper, model-binding

I am facing a strange problem inside my asp.net mvc-4 web application , as seems the `Html.Editor` is very smart in a way that lead me to get confused on how it really works.
now i have the following inside my view , where i have a main view which render a partial view , as follow:-

```
@model TS.ViewModels.ServerJoin
using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
@Html.Partial("_PMCreateAccount",Model.createAccount.operation.Details.ACCOUNTLIST.ToList())
    }
```

and here is the partial view:-

```
@model IList<TS.ViewModels.ACCOUNTLIST>
for(int i2 = start; i2 < count ; i2++) { 

    <div>

        <span class="f">@Html.DisplayName("["+i2.ToString()+"].ACCOUNTNAME") </span>@Html.Editor("["+i2.ToString()+"].ACCOUNTNAME") 


        <span class="f">@Html.DisplayName("["+i2.ToString()+"].PASSWORD") </span>@Html.Editor("["+i2.ToString()+"].PASSWORD") 
       <span class="f">@Html.DisplayName("["+i2.ToString()+"].NOTES") </span>@Html.Editor("["+i2.ToString()+"].NOTES") </div>

    }
```

and the Post action method looks as follow:-

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(ServerJoin sj,List<ACCOUNTLIST> al)
    {
      if(ModelState.IsValid)
           {
           }
      return View(sj); 

    }
```

now let say i submit the view , then the sj & al will get the correct values.. but let say a model state error is raised , then my main view will be rendered again .. now what get me confused is that the `Html.Editor` inside the partial view were able to read their original values without defining this inside my post action method:-

```
    sj.createAccount.operation.Details.ACCOUNTLIST = al;
```

i mean inside my main view i am passing the following to the partial view:-

```
@Html.Partial("_PMCreateAccount",Model.createAccount.operation.Details.ACCOUNTLIST.ToList())
```

and the `Model.createAccount.operation.Details.ACCOUNTLIST.ToList()` will be empty in-case the view is rendered after a model validation error... i thought that the `Html.Editor` will not be able to read their original values unless i explicitly assign this inside the post action method:-

```
    sj.createAccount.operation.Details.ACCOUNTLIST = al;
```

but this is not the case? so can anyone advice how my `Html.Editor` were able to get their values although the model being passed from the main view will be empty when the view is rendered after a model validation error??

Answer (score 1):

Nothing matters but what's in `ModelState`. MVC uses values from a variety of places, including the model, `ViewBag`, `ViewData` and `Request`, to fill in `ModelState`. What displays in your form is what is set in `ModelState` regardless of what's actually set on the model.

Comment: so what is the priority here... now i know that the html helpers will always use the value from the modelstate unless i am not posting back the values from the view,, in that case it will show the values from another places.. but in my case i am explicitly passing the model from my main view to my partial view,,, and the model will have empty collection of accoutlist... but Html.Editor still read the correct values!!

Comment: can you adivce on my 2 questions to get a better understanding ..so even if i am passing a model to my partial view,, the partial view HTml.Editor will still check the original values inside the Post data?

second question.. is this a behavior inside the Html helpers including Html.Editor , Html.EditorFor & Html.TextBox & Html.TextBoxFor??? i mean if i use raw html as follow <input type="text"> then i should expect different behavior ?

Regards